# How to replace date -d from script running on Linux to get it working on AIX

Tags: date, ksh, aix

On a Linux system I'm running a bash script what is running fine, but now I want to use the same script on an AIX system.
Only a small part of it isn't able to run because on the AIX system the command "date -d" is not working.
Below is the code that is running on the linux server, baised on the hostname in this case system1 and system2 a script will run only on a Sunday at the given time.

```
        declare -A myservertime
        myservertime["system1"]="02:00"
        myservertime["system2"]="02:10"

        for keys in "${!myservertime[@]}";
            do
                if [[ "$keys" == "$HOSTNAME" ]]; then
                    mylaunchtime=${myservertime["$keys"]}
                fi
            done
        if [ -z "$mylaunchtime" ]; then
            echo "Server not found."
            exit
        fi

        timenow=$(date +"%s")
        weekday=$(date +"%a" -d @$timenow )
        timerun=$(date +"%s" -d ${mylaunchtime} )
        if [ $timerun -lt $timenow ]; then
            timerun=$(( timerun + 86400 ))
        fi
        sleep_time=$(( timerun - timenow ))

        #Check is weekday = Sunday
        if [ $weekday == "Sun" ]; then
                #If Sunday then wait until starttime is reached, until then sleep
                sleep $sleep_time
                #If starttime is reached execute startprogram
                startprogram
        fi
```

I already fixed the declare part, this is also not working on AIX, to the following:
`typeset -A myservertime=(["pvm00066"]="02:30" ["pvm00100"]="01:30")`

But I have troubles to get the variables $weekday and $timerun working, because of that "date -d $variable"

Anyone here that can help me with this, I tried and searched all kind of stuff but I was unable to get one working.

Comment: Can you use `crontab` or `at`?

Comment: The script itself is getting started using crontab. Stopping and starting of the applications will be done in the script itself. That way I don't have to use multiple versions of the script, but I can simply use this script on all of the needed AIX servers.

Comment: I would recommend using perl, as that's available cross-platform and could do the date math.

Answer (score 0):

When you do want to have an identical crontab and script on all systems, and you only want to run the script on Sunday, just use an offset from 00:00.
Crontab:

```
0 0 * * 7 start_with_delay.sh
```

start_with_delay.sh:

```
declare -A myservertime
myserversleep["system1"]=7200
myserversleep["system2"]=7800
sleep ${myserversleep[HOSTNAME]}
startprogram
```

When you do not need fixed starting times for the different hosts, but only want different hosts to have different starting times, you can consider using the the last number of the IP as an input for calculating the sleep time.

Two reasons why you might consider another solution:

1. Starting a job with crontab, that starts with sleeping, is very confusing.
   An operator reading the crontab expects something to start at the time given in the crontab.
   Using a scriptname like sleep_and_start helps a little.
2. When the system reboots at Sunday 01:00, nothing is started at 02:00
   The sleep command has been stopped during the reboot.

I would try to find a smart install script, that will write a different crontab on each host. Something with Ansible, a Puppet template or shellscript.

```
case $HOSTNAME in
system1)
   starthour=2
   startminute=0
;;
system2)
   starthour=2
   startminute=10
;;
*)
   echo "No scheduled startprogram on ${HOSTNAME}.
   exit 0
;;
esac
echo "${startminute} ${starthour} * * SUN startprogram" | crontab -
```

When you want to update en existing crontab, you might want something like

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null && echo "${startminute} ${starthour} * * 7 startprogram") |
   sort -u | crontab -
```

Comment: The cron record must be: `0 0 * * 7 start_with_delay.sh`, cron do not expect symbol names

Comment: On my Linux system `man -s5 crontab` shows "Names can also be used for the 'month' and 'day of week' fields.  Use the first three letters of the particular day or month (case doesn't matter).". I did not check AIX, using 7 will be a safe choice. I changed my answer.

Comment: On AIX cron expect number. It can be 0 or 7 (both are Sunday) :)